# Trim Double Quote from JSON value using Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code that will grab the value of **RANK** if the age is above 20. However, take a look at my JSON file:

```
[
    {
         "Age" : 22
         "Rank": 100
    }
    {
         "Age" : 64
         "Rank": "20"
    }
    {
         "Age" : 19
         "Rank": 10
    }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

The actual database is longer than this example; it reaches hundred thousand. Noticed that some of the data are messed up because some **Rank** are written as String.

What should I do to grab all the **Rank** value without a problem? Do I need to make another script that trims the quotation mark, if exist, in Rank value?

Edit: My Python code

```
# assume 'file' is a file that I passed in argument during code execution
thefile = open(file)
thedata = json.load(thefile, encoding="latin1")

myContainer = []

for person in thedata:
    if person["Age"] > 20:
        myContainer.append(person["Rank"])

# Here is the issue why I can't let Rank be String
print sum(myContainer)/ len(myContainer)
```

UPDATE**

My expected output is [20, 10] instead of [u'20, 10].

Then when I average it, it should print a number instead of error.

Comment: Where is your code, we need to see to give you suggestions

Comment: I suggest that you modify your example and show every possible way of referring to 'Rank' (including Strings and question marks).

Comment: @user7568042 updated.

Comment: @DYZ I'm afraid I don't understand your request. Sorry. What do you suggest me to do again?

Comment: Can you state your expected output?

Comment: @PaulRooney Sure. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this on one line, but for the purpose of making this simple to understand this works just fine.

```
newList = []

for item in yourList:

    if int(item["age"]) > 20:
        newlist.append(int(item["rank"]))

print newList
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of steps here, you could merge them if you wanted. It's not strictly required to remap the list to have int versions of `Rank` up front.

First step is to make all instances of `Rank` be an int value, by replacing the strings in those values with their int equivalent.

Then filter out any values with an `Age` that is not above 20.

Now you have a reduced list of the original data, so map that to contain just the `Rank`.

```
import json
from operator import itemgetter

data = '''[
    {
        "Age" : 22,
        "Rank": 100
    },
    {
        "Age" : 64,
        "Rank": "20"
    },
    {
        "Age" : 19,
        "Rank": 10
    }
]'''

def paramtoint(param):
    def fn(d):
        d[param] = int(d[param])
        return d
    return fn

fixed = map(paramtoint('Rank'), json.loads(data))

over20 = filter(lambda x: x['Age'] > 20 , fixed)

print(map(itemgetter('Rank'), over20))
```

Output

> [100, 20]

Comment: Cool it might be a bit more than you strictly need to do just that but hopefully might be more useful if you want to transform your data to get rid of those inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
ranklist = [int(_["rank"]) for _ in array if 20 < _["age"]]
```

where array is a python list of dicts parsed from the json file shown in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't use the variable `_` unless you don't intend to use it.

Comment: Hi, what will be the result from this? Is it like `ranklist = [20, 10]` where all of them are int?

Comment: @ThomasWest: Yes, they'll all be ints. If the rank value in an entry is, say "??", the element in ranklist will wind up being 0 . This expression does the same thing as Paul's solution -- for the entries where age is over 20, turn rank into an int and store it.

Comment: @Paul Rooney: in this case we're just using _ to build the list that gets assigned to ranklist. He'll then go through ranklist to see what he got.

Comment: @TomBarron the convention is to use `_` for a variable that is not used. Most developers would expect this. No biggie but just so you know.